# Duplicate Explorer icons on taskbar - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, taskbar

I have an intermittent problem with pinned icons on the taskbar. Sometimes when I click on the pinned Windows Explorer icon, it opens a duplicate icon on the taskbar. This doesn't happen every time I log on, but it does happen frequently.

[image]

In the image above, the left icon is the pinned Explorer icon. When I click this, it opens another Explorer icon (the one on the right). I've tried:

- Unpinning Explorer and re-pinning the root application (not a shortcut)
- Pinning the newly opened icon (this just results in two pinned Explorer icons)
- checking the path `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` for unwanted icons

but I haven't been able to solve this annoying problem.

Comment: If you unpin the icon and reboot, does the icon remain gone or does it return?

Comment: I unpinned and rebooted and it's fine again, but the problem is that this is an intermittent but recurring issue. For example, yesterday there was no issue with duplicates on the taskbar, but when I booted the computer today, there was. I don't think I made any significant changes to the system in the meantime, so I don't know what is causing the issue.

Comment: Do you run software for backups or scripts that modify anything in the above folder, or making changes to the registry? These 2 locations are what pins an icon to the taskbar.

Comment: I don't think so. I use CCleaner for maintenance. I use Google Filestream for backups.